# Is it possible to validate the xmlns:fb (Facebook) attribute?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like

I have a Facebook Like button on my site and as such also have the `xmlns:fb` attribute on the `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

However, when running my site through the W3C validator, I get these errors:

> Line 2, Column 61: Attribute xmlns:fb not allowed here.
>
> Line 2, Column 61: Attribute with the local name xmlns:fb is not serializable as XML 1.0.
>
> Line 222, Column 72: Attribute fb:like:layout is not serializable as XML 1.0.
>
> Line 222, Column 72: Attribute fb:like:layout not allowed on element a at this point.

It is my understanding that using the `xmlns:fb` attribute adds `fb` to the document namespace, so that using any `<fb:` element is valid. Is that not the case? Is it a HTML5 issue?

I also have similar validation errors with the Twitter button, is it possible to fix those as well?

> Line 223, Column 53: Attribute tw:via is not serializable as XML 1.0.
>
> Line 223, Column 53: Attribute tw:via not allowed on element a at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to validate `xmlns:fb` with HTML5.

However, you can use the new `data-...`-attributes, which were added by Facebook and are valid HTML5, as described [here](http://fbml5.blogspot.com/).

This is an example of how you can use this extension in HTML5 (assume all code is in the body element):

```
<h3>Members</h3>
<embed data-fb="login-button" data-show-faces="true" />
<h3>Recent activity</h3>
<embed data-fb="activity" data-site="***" data-width="200" data-header="false"
 data-border_color="#fff" data-recommendations="false" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<!-- the JavaScript API -->
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<!-- the extention script from this article -->
<script src="/scripts/fb.js"></script>
<script>
 //<![CDATA[
 FB.init({apiKey: '***', appId: '***', status: true, cookie: true, fbml5: true});
 //]]>
</script>
```

This would be the equivalent XHTML code:

```
<h3>Members</h3>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" />
<h3>Recent activity</h3>
<fb:activity site="***" width="200" header="false"
 border_color="#fff" recommendations="false" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<!-- the JavaScript API -->
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<!-- the extention script from this article -->
<script src="/scripts/fb.js"></script>
<script>
 //<![CDATA[
 FB.init({apiKey: '***', appId: '***', status: true, cookie: true, fbml5: true});
 //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 30):

Or you can now use [prefix mappings](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/#scoping-of-prefix-mappings).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="fb: http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: works.. funny me, I didn't remove the other properties. Thanks