# Where do I start on cleaning up this html and removing all errors

Tags: html

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefittestblogger.com%2F

You will see all the errors at the link. my biggest issue is do I delete that from my html, move it, or change it completely and to what? **HELP** A few of the errors are below.

**Error: Bad value service.post for attribute rel on element link**: The string service.post is not a registered keyword.

```
<link rel="service.post" type="application/atom+xml" title="The Fittest Blogger   - Atom" href="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/6217016279816988858/posts/default" />
```

**Error: & did not start a character reference.** (& probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

```
016279816988858&zx=bbac2b82-18
```

**Error: Stray end tag style**.

```
style>↩--></style>↩<styl
```

**Error: Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context**.

```
 ></style>↩<style id='template-skin-1' type='text/css'><!--↩b
```

**Error: Stray end tag head**.

```
</script></head>↩<body
```

**Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.**

```
 t></head>↩<body class='loading'>↩<!--
```

**Fatal Error**: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

```
 t></head>↩<body class='loading'>↩<!--
```

Comment: Questions that are asked on SO should not only help you but also other people having the same problem. Because of that you need to include the a minimal example reproduce your problem with the question. The problem with your question is, that it is on the one hand generic and that the problem will not be reproduce-able as soon as you fixed it on your page. In addition the individual error are already asked and answered here e.g. [Is it possible to validate the xmlns:fb (Facebook) attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696026)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow, so I did not know how stringent the posting rules were. But your answer is just for the part of the problem. Its clear now the HTML doesn't allow 'xlmns:b' but I still had other issues in my HTML. Other people could have the same issues, but I dont know what other people are working on. So I really dont understand how I am supposed to use this site efficiently, if im not allowed to ask questions like this one.

Comment: You are allowed, but for your example you should e.g. include the error message in your question. But only the relevant parts of them. Otherwise when you correct your error on your page then the link `https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefittestblogger.com%2F`  would not show any errors anymore, so this post will be useless at the that time.

Answer (score 1):

You always should fix errors step by step because the error shown might result because of a previous one.

**Bad value service.post for attribute rel on element link**

Is already answered here [How to solve this error : Bad value original-source for attribute rel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231274)

As the error tells you `rel` can't be `service.post` valid values for `rel` are defined here: [W3C: HTML5 4.8.4 Link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)

**Error: & did not start a character reference.**

`&` have a special meaning and need to be escaped. As the message tells you you need to use `&amp;` instead of `&`

**Error: Stray end tag style.**
As the message tells you have an `</style>` tag at that position that does not have a corresponding opening tag. So you most likely need to remove it.